# Flutter CheckboxListTile secondary widget function

Tags: flutter

Using the CheckboxListTile widget with an edit icon as the secondary widget.

I want to be able to edit each item in the Checkbox list.

!(https://ibb.co/m0Gc3Gx)

What is a good way of adding a function to be able to edit each item in the CheckboxListTile.

```
 Widget _buildItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    final remind = reminders[index];

    return CheckboxListTile(
      value: remind.isDone,
      title: Text(remind.title + "-" + remind.message),
      secondary: const Icon(Icons.edit),
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
      onChanged: (bool isChecked) {
        onRemindToggle(remind, isChecked);
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hook up the secondary widget to a function"? Can you elaborate.

Comment: Thanks John, I updated the description and I hope it make more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

There could be a better way of doing this. But giving a brief idea about how to achieve it is as follows:

```
static String name = "John";

  Map<String, bool> values = {
    name: true,
  };

  Widget checkbox()
  {
    return ListView(
        children: values.keys.map((String key) {
          return new CheckboxListTile(
            title: new Text(name),
            value: values[key],
            secondary: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  name = "James";                                  
                });
                print("Name is : $name");
              },
            ),
            controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                values[key] = value;
              });
            },
          );
        }).toList(),
      );
  }
```

which would result into something like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIdF2.jpg).

And when edit icon is pressed the field changes from john to James. Similarly you can edit the code as per your need.
Hope it helped:)

Comment: Thanks John, this helped me in the correct direction.